# dump time stamps of views and votes

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, research

I was told by team@stackoverflow.com to try to post the following as a feature-request. I'm a scientist, and a few colleagues and I are interested in how networks of tagged knowledge units(bits) evolve. In the file stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z
(from https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) I saw the view counts (total up to now) and scores of posts. Can the Admins export from the DB and provide for research purposes the time stamps of all views and all score change events? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, and pretty sure about it, views are not logged anywhere in the database except for increasing the counter so timestamps are not possible. As for score change events it's possible, as each question got a timeline showing it.

Comment: I answered your question about this on Meta Stack Overflow a few days ago... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258335/stack-overflow-posts-dump-time-stamps-of-views-and-score-changes

Comment: Thanks, found the votes' time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tables (files if you use the datadump) that hold an history of *events* for posts.

First of all there is Votes. Each row hold a postid, creationdate and votetypeid (among other attributes). The votetypeid hold the type of vote. The most relevant ones are:

1. AcceptedByOriginator
2. UpMod
3. DownMod

Do note that `creationdate` only contains the date part. The time is zero-ed out to guarantee anonymity for the voters.

Secondly there is PostHistory. It keeps track of a various of events. You'll find postid, creationdate (including exact time) and a posthistorytypeid. With that attribute you can find values for:

10. Post Closed
11. Post Reopened
12. Post Deleted
13. Post Undeleted
19. Question Protected
20. Question Unprotected

for event 10, the attribute `text` will hold the close voters. Other events might capture similar or other data in the `text`attribute, often encoded as an JSON string.

For a complete description of the schema available in both the data dump as [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) please see [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)